# Configuring bridged network card on VMWare VM - Host : Windows 7 - Guest : Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-player, ubuntu-server

My question is about giving Internet connection to a VM with a STATIC IP address, by connecting to the WiFi I have at home. 
I gave my VM, running Ubuntu Server 12.04 on VMWare Player, one network adapter using the bridged mode, so that the VM is directly added to the physical network (WiFi). I did no network setup on my Windows 7 host.

So what I first did, after setting the network on VMWare Player, was to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file of my guest OS (Ubuntu Server) and put the following

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I restarted the network service with

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

My VM got the IP 192.168.1.5 and I could ping google.com and the gateway, but not my Windows 7 host machine connected to the Wifi ... Why is that ? What did I not do ?

Then I changed the /etc/network/interfaces file, and gave my VM a static IP, equal to the one it had gotten from the DHCP server before (192.168.1.5)

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254 #same as showed in the result of ipconfig on my W7 host
```

I restarted the network, and I could only ping the gateway. I could not ping google.com or the W7 host (192.168.1.4)

What am I missing to just connect my VM to the Wifi ?? 
Thanks a lot for your help. Don't hesitate to redirect me to useful resources.

Comment: Worked more on my problem, and it's almost solved. The steps are 1- disable all vm adapters on host 2- take the wifi card properties, and enable "vmware bridged protocol" The wifi card should be the only NIC to have "vmware bridged protocol" enabled 3- go to vmware (player or workstation) and set up one network adapter, in bridged mode 4- go into your vm, and assign your vm a static IP address on the wifi network and restart the networking service. You should be able to ping google.com --- PROBLEM : I can't ping my host machine, while I should. I need help on why that doesn't work

Comment: Disable the firewall for pinging the host.

Comment: Well, if you arrive at an answer, please post it as such. Then, after some timed has passed, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved disabling **Citrix DNE Lightweight Filter** from my network adapter properties.
If you are using a Realteck adapter, you can take a look at [KB1025978](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025978) and [KB1015940](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015940)

You can check this question

[VMware Workstation Bridged Network Host UnReachable](https://superuser.com/questions/617696/vmware-workstation-bridged-network-host-unreachable)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with W7 host and Linux guests with bridged network. No Host/Guest connectivity, other remote connections work fine. Disabling Link Layer Topology Discovery drivers in the Networking properties of my Local Area Connection solved the issue.