# How to bridge network connection between host and guest OS in VMWare Player

Tags: networking, vmware-player, bridge, wireless-bridge

My host OS is windows 8 and my guest OS is lubuntu. Basically, I am trying to run a Django server form my guest OS on `0.0.0.0:8000` so that I can access it from my host OS.

I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551658/how-to-access-django-development-server-on-virtual-machine-from-actual-computer/24196193#24196193) how I can access the server from my host OS on stackoverflow.

In the post, one of the users suggested that I should change the network to 'bridge-mode'. What I tried was this:

1. I went to VMWare Player
2. Clicked 'Player -> Manage -> Virtual Machine Settings'
3. Changed 'Network Adapter' from 'NAT' to 'Bridged'

After doing this, my guest OS lost internet connection. I ran the django server on `0.0.0.0:8000` and could access it by going to either `0.0.0.0:8000` OR `192.168.174.233:8000` from the guest OS (my guest OS's IP address is `192.168.174.233`.. my host OS's IP address is `192.168.2.37`), but I couldn't access it from either of the two links from the host OS..

Am I bridging the connect correctly or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: VMware will sometimes disable a network connection when you change the adapter type so double-check that. In addition, you might need to restart the interface (ifdown eth0; ifup eth0) or restart the system. Bridge will attach the VM directly to the host's network, Host-only creates a network that only the VM and host exist in, and NAT is basically the same as Host only except VMware will also perform NAT between the Host-only network and the actual network the host is connected too, if necessary. Any of those should work assuming you're using the correct IP address and firewalls aren't enabled

Comment: Do an "ip addr", "sudo netstat -tlpn" (while the Django server is running), and "sudo ufw status" on the guest. That will show you the guest's IP address(es), what programs are listening on TCP ports, and whether you have uncomplicated firewall (ufw) turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved disabling **Citrix DNE Lightweight Filter** from my network adapter properties.
If you are using a Realteck adapter, you can take a look at [KB1025978](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025978) and [KB1015940](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015940)

You can check this question
[VMware Workstation Bridged Network Host UnReachable](https://superuser.com/questions/617696/vmware-workstation-bridged-network-host-unreachable)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to try adding a host-only network? In preferences, under the network tab, add a host only network (vboxnet0). Then go to your VM and add it as a second network adapter. Finally, when you're running your server, make sure you host on `0.0.0.0`,